# Does Angular's cdkMenu not work with ngModel or forms? The position of the template are no longer next to the button

Tags: angular, popupmenu, angular-cdk

I would like to create a menu bar for the tipTap text editor. The menu's popovers with heading selection, text color selection etc. work very well, because there are only buttons in the menu. Now i want to add another menu item that opens two inputs to enter one link and a placeholder text. the moment i open the menu, the menu does not appear under the button like the other popUps. It appears on the top right edge. i have used ngModel or form for the inputs. when i delete the ngModel or form. it appears under the menu icon as i expected. i think that the directives ngModel or forms do not work together with the cdkMenue. is this true? the popup closing functionality is also broken.

Here is my html:

```html
 <div cdkMenuBar> 
... menuItems ...
<div class='separator'></div>
  <!-- text link -->
  <button
    cdkMenuItem
    type='button'
    class='button'
    title='Platzhalter Link'
    [cdkMenuTriggerFor]='linkMenu'
  >
    <mat-icon class='small'>link</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <!-- link menu -->
  <ng-template #linkMenu>
    <div class='r-color-menu' cdkMenu>
      <form formGroupName='linkPlaceholderForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()'>
        <input type='text' formControlName='link'
               [placeholder]="'link...'"
        />
        <input
          type='text' formControlName='placeholder'
          [placeholder]="'placeholder...'"
        />

        <button (click)='setLink()'>
          setLink
        </button>
        <button (click)='unsetLink()'>
          unsetLink
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <div class='separator'></div>

... menuItems ...
</div>
```

[image: The red container is the one I created with the input and the green one is the one with the buttons in it. Actually, my red container should look exactly like the green one.]

The red container is the one I created with the input and the green one is the one with the buttons in it. Actually, my red container should look exactly like the green one.

how can i create the menu?

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz repro ?

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty repro. However, the behaviour is not as I have described. Here are all the sub menus at the top left. And not under the menu buttons. that mens my css is corrupt.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uero1q?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, when I ran into something similar when using cdkMenu, the issue was that I had absolute positioning on the menu element. **Removing that from my CSS fixed the issue.** Your Stackblitz doesn't have any positioning on the menu element, so perhaps you ran into the same issue as I had.

In case it's relevant, addressing another couple of issues with your Stackblitz fixes some of the behavior, namely:

1. You have two templates with the same templateRef.
2. The documentation for [CDK Menu](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/overview) has the templates outside of the element containing the menu bar.
3. You have a `formGroupName` without a parent FormGroup directive.

See the [forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xefdfp?) to see how the fixes changed the behavior.